# Кнопка с эффектами

Tags: delphi

Как написать компонент-кнопку, чтобы при наведении курсора на кнопку отображалась другая
картинка. Желательно с исходником. Или где взять такой компонент (бесплатный) для Delphi 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставите на форму кнопку Button, ImageList. Заносите в ImageList картинки. В свойстве кнопки Images выбираете ImageList. Дальше код:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  Button1.ImageIndex:= 1;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  Button1.ImageIndex:= 0;
 end;
```

Продвинутые настройки визуализации компонентов представлены в FireMonkey Delphi XE2.

Comment: ммм, это то что я имел ввиду токо просто без имаджлиста

Answer (score 2):

Сначала стоит рассмотреть, подходит ли для ваших задач [`TBitBtn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Buttons.TBitBtn). Можно попробовать, используя обработчики контрола `OnMouseEnter` и `OnMouseLeave`, менять рисунок на лету.

Answer (score 0):

Ну насчет компонентов не знаю, но у меня тоже была такая задача, я взял две картинки кнопок одна из которых типа в покое, а другая когда наведут, и просто вставил их в делфи, при наведении на одну кнопку на место неё ставится другая, а при отведении ставилась обратно.